# How can a datapump export have its resource usage limited on linux?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, datapump, export

Doing an export of a number of users causes high CPU and I/O usage.  I can mitigate the effects of the CPU usage using Resource Manager and setting the export session to a low priority group, but how can I limit the disk I/O?  I am not running the operation in parallel and have already read Oracle's [Datapump Performance](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_perf.htm) documentation.  Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Ionice can limit disk usage**

Take a look at the [ionice utility](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-set-io-scheduling-class-priority.html) for linux, as it seems to suit your needs quite well.

Comment: Great answer, unfortunately I need to do this on windows, but since I didn't specify that I'll accept your answer and tag this for linux and then ask again with a windows tag.